# Which sentence structure is correct and why?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, modifiers, construction

1. I have typed nearly all the sentences.
2. I nearly have typed all the sentences.

Also, do I need to add the preposition 'of' to the sentence? E.g. "I have nearly typed all of the sentences."

Comment: _Nearly_ qualifies _all_, so (1) is correct. _Of_ is optional.

Comment: If you wanted nevertheless to write #2, "I have nearly typed all the sentences," would sound more idiomatic. It would not mean the same thing as #1, however. "Nearly" would no longer qualify "all". It would qualify "typed", and would suggest that you had partially typed all the sentences.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had encountered a similar sat practice question but couldn't understand the idea.